# How to take screenshot of a total custom listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

Here is my code to get screenshot of customlistview which contains two textviews side by side. I followed some stackoverflow questions tried by getting each listitem and adding all to bitmap then saving that to gallery.

```
public static Bitmap getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap() {

    ListView listview    = MyActivity.mFocusedListView;
    ListAdapter adapter  = listview.getAdapter(); 
    int itemscount       = adapter.getCount();
    int allitemsheight   = 0;
    List<Bitmap> bmps    = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {

        View childView      = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);
        childView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
        childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        childView.buildDrawingCache();
        bmps.add(childView.getDrawingCache());
        allitemsheight+=childView.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    Bitmap bigbitmap    = Bitmap.createBitmap(listview.getMeasuredWidth(), allitemsheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas bigcanvas    = new Canvas(bigbitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int iHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
        Bitmap bmp = bmps.get(i);
        bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
        iHeight+=bmp.getHeight();

        bmp.recycle();
        bmp=null;
    }

    return bigbitmap;
}
```

but I am getting nullpointer exception here

```
childView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), 
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));`and stacktrace for error.
```

I don't get what the problem is in this code.

```
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:465)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15371)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at com.globussoft.mothistorycheck.Result_Activity.getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap(Result_Activity.java:218)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at com.globussoft.mothistorycheck.Result_Activity.onClick(Result_Activity.java:144)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-17 19:28:36.341: E/AndroidRuntime(7806):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Are there any alternative way to get screenshot of total listview in android ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public static Bitmap getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap(ListView listview, String path) {

    ListAdapter adapter = listview.getAdapter();
    int itemscount = adapter.getCount();
    int allitemsheight = 0;
    List<Bitmap> bmps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {
        listview.setSelection(i);
        View childView = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = childView.getLayoutParams();
        if (lp == null) {
            lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-2,-2);
        }
        lp.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        lp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        childView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        childView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
        childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        childView.buildDrawingCache();
        bmps.add(childView.getDrawingCache());
        allitemsheight += childView.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    Bitmap bigbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(listview.getMeasuredWidth(), allitemsheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas bigcanvas = new Canvas(bigbitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int iHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
        Bitmap bmp = bmps.get(i);
        if (bmp != null) {
            bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
            iHeight += bmp.getHeight();

            bmp.recycle();
            bmp = null;
        }
    }
    return bigbitmap;
}
```